# is qgraphicsitems actual height and width is different from sceneboundingrect when it gets transformed

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a code for qgraphicsitem to be move and transform in Qgraghicsscene but when I transform it, its actual height and width is different from its sceneboundingrect.
why it is so?
actuallu I have to draw outline around transformed item but that outline should be sceneboundingrect of item and not its own.
How could I manage it??
Please replay with your answers.
Thanks in advance.

Here my code sample
code below is in paint function of qgraphicsitem

```
if(bRegionSelected)
{

    _outterborderPen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
    painter->setPen(_outterborderPen);
    QPointF topLeft(_drawingOrigenX, _drawingOrigenY);
    QPointF bottomRight( _drawingWidth, _drawingHeight);

    painter->setBrush(Qt::gray);
    QRectF rect2(topLeft, bottomRight);
    painter->setOpacity(0.6);
    painter->drawRect(rect2);
    painter->setOpacity(1);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern));
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black));

    painter->drawRect(_drawingOrigenX, _drawingOrigenY, nHandlerWidth, nHandlerWidth);
    painter->drawRect(_drawingWidth-nHandlerWidth-2, _drawingOrigenY, nHandlerWidth, nHandlerWidth);
    painter->drawRect(_drawingOrigenX, _drawingHeight-nHandlerWidth-2, nHandlerWidth, nHandlerWidth);
    painter->drawRect(_drawingWidth-nHandlerWidth-2, _drawingHeight-nHandlerWidth-2, nHandlerWidth, nHandlerWidth);

    qDebug() << "here in paint :: " << sceneBoundingRect() << "and" << _drawingWidth << _drawingHeight;

    if(transform().isRotating())
    {
        qDebug() << "here in paint for ratating :::: " << _drawingHeight-sceneBoundingRect().height();
        _outterborderPen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
        painter->setPen(_outterborderPen);
        QPointF topLeft1(int(0), int(_drawingHeight-sceneBoundingRect().height()));
        QPointF bottomRight1(_drawingWidth, sceneBoundingRect().height());
        QRectF rect21(topLeft1, bottomRight1);
        painter->setOpacity(0.2);
        painter->drawRect(rect21);
    }
}
else
{
    painter->setPen(Qt::black);
    QPointF topLeft(_drawingOrigenX, _drawingOrigenX);
    QPointF bottomRight(_drawingWidth, _drawingHeight);
    QRectF rect2(topLeft, bottomRight);
    painter->setOpacity(1);
    painter->drawRect(rect2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're implementing this function in a subclass of QGraphicsItem. I think you need to use `boundingRect()` instead of `sceneBoundingRect()` if you want to get the rectangle around the item.

`sceneBoundingRect()` always changes, for example when the item is rotated, but `boundingRect()` of it stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but actually I want to draw rectangle of its sceneboundingrect.

Comment: yes you are write, but how can I access boundingRect of item in another class i.e. in class where I am using it???

Comment: @AbhijeetBhilare For example: `QGraphicsItem *item; item->boundingRect();` If you're sublassing it, for example with the name of  `myGraphicsItem`, you can do `myGraphicsItem *item; item->boundingRect();`

Comment: @AbhijeetBhilare `boundingRect()` has the same attributes as `sceneBoundingRect()`

Comment: And why does sceneboundingrect gets change when it is transformed?

Comment: @AbhijeetBhilare Because sceneBoundingRect() draws a non-rotated rectangle around items. For example when an item is rotated for 45 degrees, sceneBoundingRect is a bigger rectangle with 90 degrees.

Comment: No problem. I don't know the exact problem, but it should be public. Do you have a code in your header file that moves boundingRect to protected?